# StackViews Views and Shadows

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I am currently working to build my UI with the use of xcode/storyboard. I have a situation where my shadows are under my next stack view row. I tried to bring the UIView1 to front without any luck. There is no gap between the "rows". I see the shadows when I changed the height of UIView1 so I know I have a shadow.

```
StackView
---- Row with UIView1 + Shadow
---- Row with UIView2
---- Row etc..
```

I'm missing something but can't get it to work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a separate root view. Just take the shadow out of the stack view, put it above, then use Autolayout constraints to put it right below your `UIView1` where it should be (`shadow.top = view1.bottom` or so to say).

Autolayout is not reserved to constraints between siblings or children, you can add rules between any view in your view hierarchy.

Comment: So a new uiview with minimum height and add shadow to that uiview and move this outside the stackview so that it on top?

Comment: Yep. Or even simpler, a `UIImageView` containing your shadow, or a `CAGradientLayer`, if your shadow is not too sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

Stack view are only abstract container for views, Stack view does not get rendered on view, So If you are trying to add shadow on stack view then i suppose -

**You have to place a view before stack view For this follow following steps**

1. embed a root view to the stack view on which you are willing to add shadow.
2. Add shadow on that root view.

Comment: Well i have the shadow on my uiview that is working but i think its now showing under my next view. The property masktobounds is set to false